# Showing that every subspace $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

We will show that every subspace $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has a basis. We note that the empty set $\{\}$ is a basis for the zero subspace $\left\{0\right\}$, since a linear combination (sum) of an empty set of vectors is defined to be the zero vector (similarly, the empty product is defined to be $1$).
1. Let $B_0 := \left\{\right\}$. Show that if $S\neq \textit{span}(B_0)$, then there is a vector $v_1\in S \, \backslash \, \text{span}(B_0)$, for which $B_1 := \left\{v_1\right\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $S$.
2. Show that if $S\neq \text{span}(B_1)$, then there is a linearly independent $B_2 = \left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$ of $S$.
3. Continuing in this way, show there must be an $m$ for which $B_m = \left\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m\right\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $S$ which spans $S$, i.e., a basis for $S$.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: At which point are you stuck? What have you already tried?

Comment: Are you asking for proof verification? Or more detailed explanation perhaps? Ideally, it would good to have a more concrete question to work with

Comment: Right sorry. I’m looking for proof & a detailed explanation. Where do I even begin?

Comment: Did you try prove the first step?

Comment: If $B_1$ spans $S$, then it is a basis for $S$. If it doesn’t span $S$, then there is some vector $B_2$ in $S$ but not in $\text{span}(B_1)$ so that the set $\{B_1,B_2\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Continue this way by adjoining more vectors $A_3,\ldots,A_k$ In $S$ where possible while maintaining that $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ is linearly independent. This process terminates when $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ spans $S$. Am I on the right path or on a completely different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the assumption about $\ S\,\ $ being a subspace of $\ \mathbb R^A,\ $ where $\ A\ $ is a **finite** set (and $\ \mathbb R^A\ $ is the set of all functions $\ x:A\rightarrow\mathbb R$).

It's not a place here to say a lot but nevertheless, the construction below has several important implications which go beyond the scope of the given Q.

=====================================

Case $\ A=\emptyset\ $ is trivial. Let $\ A\ne\emptyset.\ $

Define (construct by induction), a decreasing sequence of linear subspaces

$$ S=S_1 \supseteq S_2 \supseteq S_3 \supseteq \ldots  $$
and two sequences of elements $\ b_k\in S_k\ \mbox{and}\ a_k\in A\ (k=1\ 2\ \ldots)\ $

-- both sequences being a priori finite or infinite -- as follows, subject to the following four conditions:

- if $\ S_n=\ \{0\}\ $ the construction stops;
- if $\ S_n\ne\ \{0\}\ $ then let $\ b_n\in S_n\setminus\{0\}\ $ be arbitrary; and then
- $\ a_n\in A\setminus \{a_k\in\ A: k<n\} $
- $\ S_{n+1}\ :=\ \{\,x\in S_n:\ \forall_{k\in 1..n}\ x(a_k)=0\,\} $

The above sequences are **finite** since $\ A\ $ was assumed to be **finite** -- at one moment we will have $\ S_{n+1}=\{0\}.\ $ Then

$$ \{b_1\ \ldots\ b_n\} $$

is the base of $S$. Obviously, that last non-zero $\ n\le|A|,\ $ i.e.

$$ \dim S\ \le\ \dim(\mathbb R^A)$$

=====================================

**REMARK 1.** *The theorem about **base** holds for arbitrary linear spaces (over arbitrary fields), including the infinite-dimensional spaces -- you don't even need to talk about subspaces (every linear subspace is a linear space, that's all that you need to know).*

*However, the above proof for the finite-dimensional case (which holds for arbitrary fields, of course) is extra useful in linear algebra.*

**REMARK 2.** *In general, when you include the infinite-dimensional spaces, the theorem about **base** requires transcendental induction or any other property of sets which is equivalent to the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice is necessary, meaning that a complete ignoring the axiom of choice will not lead to the theorem about the base.*